# Bind model explicitly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

in general,i will use the code below to make binding of Customer model,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Customer model)
{
  ...
}
```

now, i want to raise the binding later , not immediately ,like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create()
{
  //some operations first
  ...
  //binding will start here 
  var model={Bind - To - Customer}
  ...
}
```

so,how can i achieve that, is it possible ???

Thank much for any suggest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [`UpdateModel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264031.aspx) or [`TryUpdateModel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.tryupdatemodel.aspx) methods:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    //some operations first
    ...
    // binding will start here 
    var model = new Customer();
    UpdateModel(customer);
    ...
}
```